# Cannot find table 0 error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I get This error when i try to execute stored procedure and get null dataset.

```
private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["learnaspConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

protected void btnregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RegisterInsert", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@fname", txtfname.Text);
            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@lname", txtlname.Text);
            SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@company", txtcompany.Text);
            SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@phone", txtphone.Text);
            SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@address", txtaddress.Text);
            SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("@email", txtemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p5);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p6);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            ListViewDetails.DataSource = ds;
            ListViewDetails.DataBind();
            lblmessage.Visible = true;
            lblmessage.Text = "Registration Completed Successfully!";
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
        }
}
```

My stored Procedure is:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterInsert] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fname nvarchar(50),
    @lname nvarchar(50),
    @company nvarchar(50),
    @phone nvarchar(50),
    @address nvarchar(250),
    @email  nvarchar(250)   
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
        insert into [dbo].[register]
    ([fname],
     [lname],
     [company],
     [phone],
     [address],
     [email])
     values
     (@fname,
      @lname,
      @company,
      @phone,
      @address,
      @email)    
END
```

I am not able to get display data in Listview control when i run my code.Button Click event stores values in Database twice and gives error'Cannot find table 0'.

Please help me to let me know where i am wrong in my code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you expect to be in `ds.Tables`? Because you don't execute any `SELECT` statements

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() will not return a DataAdapter in any case

Comment: Indeed, as @RGraham says, your stored procedure does not return any tables, so nothing will get filled. Do you perhaps want to retunn the `Scope_Identity()` from the stored procedure? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Can i get correct code to verify where i am wrong in my code?

Comment: Don't add a SELECT to the bottom of the RegisterInsert proc, unless it's to select the single inserted row back out.  If you're wanting to display the entire table, put that in a different stored proc, and call it from a separate C# function.

Comment: yes as "@Cris" and "@RGraham" had said, your Stored Procedure will need a SELECT statement for you to return data.

then you can populate the DataSet

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the Dataset does not contain any table objects. Therefore DS.Table[0] does not exist and will thrown an error.
Add a check to ensure the dataset has tables before proceeding.

```
    // check if ds has a table
    if(DS.TABLES.COUNT>0)
    {
       //check if ds.table[0] has any rows  
       if(DS.TABLES[0].ROWS.COUNT>0){
       //do something
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["learnaspConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void btnregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RegisterInsert", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@fname", txtfname.Text);
            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@lname", txtlname.Text);
            SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@company", txtcompany.Text);
            SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@phone", txtphone.Text);
            SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@address", txtaddress.Text);
            SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("@email", txtemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p5);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p6);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from register",con);//Here  you are using same cmd that is for insert so you call insert procedure twice and that's why insert data twice 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            ListViewDetails.DataSource = ds;
            ListViewDetails.DataBind();
            lblmessage.Visible = true;
            lblmessage.Text = "Registration Completed Successfully!";


            con.Close();

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's good . But can you explain this line ? DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]; why you set the index value ????

Comment: Can i know how to show all data rows values already present in that table when i run my code.

Comment: if u want all data present in table when page loads you should select that in page_load event

Comment: what you should do is copy starting 6 lines from SqlDataAdapter to ListViewDetails.DataBind(); in page_Load event

Comment: Better to make a seperate function, copy those lines in it and call that function in page_load and in place of those line in btnregister_Click event.

Answer (score 0):

Totally Wrong .

**You want store values from database , need insert query**

**You want  read values from database , need select query**

But you have used insert query for select query . and **you have to call the query in 2 time ( dataadapter and executenonquery)**,So the data inserted twice .

first read this article [**Msdn**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070)

Answer (score 0):

You are using insert query so you are getting null DataTable.
Write another select statement after insert statement.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RegisterInsert] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@fname nvarchar(50),
@lname nvarchar(50),
@company nvarchar(50),
@phone nvarchar(50),
@address nvarchar(250),
@email  nvarchar(250)   
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into [dbo].[register]
([fname],
 [lname],
 [company],
 [phone],
 [address],
 [email])
 values
 (@fname,
  @lname,
  @company,
  @phone,
  @address,
  @email)

select * from [dbo].[register]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the line: `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);`

Its good that you created an adapter. But two issue are there in above line:

1.) The above  method is actually used to specify the `SelectCommand` of `SqlDataAdapter` .
    [Check MSDN here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)

2.) You havent specified what  `SqlConnection` to use to this adapter. 
So do this way:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
```

where `conn` is your `SqlConnection` object.

Seeing the last 8 lines of your code, it seems basically you want to display the data.

**So once you execute your query: the Line**: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` , **now change your** `cmd` **and assign either a stored procedure that does the**  `Select` Query

OR

You can specif Select query in `cmd` as : `Select * from register` , but then you need to change the command type also as: `cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;`

Answer (score 0):

```
             con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RegisterInsert", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@fname", txtfname.Text);
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@lname", txtlname.Text);
        SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@company", txtcompany.Text);
        SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@phone", txtphone.Text);
        SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@address", txtaddress.Text);
        SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("@email", txtemail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p5);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p6);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        ListViewDetails.DataSource = dt;
        ListViewDetails.DataBind();
        con.close();
        lblmessage.Visible = true;
        lblmessage.Text = "Registration Completed Successfully!";
```

you have not properly defined datatable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Bind of datasource in this way

```
 ListViewDetails.DataSource = dt;
```

Now close the connection after binding the data.

```
con.close();
```

This code will work.