# C# Datagridview cannot find table 0

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString2);
SqlCommand cmd2;

connection.Open();

   try
   {
   cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
   cmd2.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO tbl_EmailAdress (Email) VALUES (@EmailAddress);");
   cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
   cmd2.Parameters["@EmailAddress"].Value = TxbAddEmailUser.Text;
   SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
   bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }
   TxbAddEmailUser.Clear();
```

The problem is that my program gives me the error:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: cannot find tabel 0;

this is my database:

```
table: tbl_EmailAdress
column: id, int, NOT NULL
column: Email, char(10), NULL
```

The insert query works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `adap.Fill(ds)` before `bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Comment: @ASpirin just tried it, didn't work, but thanks for helping

Comment: OutOfRange happened because `ds` does not has tables. BTW Insert command you can call directly `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: You're inserting a row that doesnt return a table.....

Comment: Where are you reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Cannot find table 0"* indicates that `DataSet` has empty tables at the first index (0), so that you can't assign data source from it.

The main problem is you're using `INSERT` command here:

```
cmd2.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO tbl_EmailAdress (Email) VALUES (@EmailAddress);");
```

`INSERT` command is not intended to return any results for [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO tbl_EmailAdress (Email) VALUES (@EmailAddress)");
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd2.Parameters["@EmailAddress"].Value = TxbAddEmailUser.Text;
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that `ExecuteNonQuery` only returns affected rows (i.e. 1 row), and you can't assign `dataGridView1.DataSource` to a single integer value.

If you want to use `SqlDataAdapter`, you need to use `SELECT` statement like this example:

```
cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM tbl_EmailAdress WHERE Email = @EmailAddress");
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd2.Parameters["@EmailAddress"].Value = TxbAddEmailUser.Text;
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds); // fill the data table from adapter
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // this time the first table is not null or empty
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Similar issue:

[Cannot find table 0 error in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272504/cannot-find-table-0-error-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

No need of doing this ,

```
   SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
   bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
   dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

just use

```
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```